# Writing a complicated if statement in js

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement

I have a list of years with id, from date and to date as follows:

- id    from_date        to_date
- 1     2013-02-12       2013-02-22
- 2     2013-03-01       2013-03-28
- 3     2013-03-29       2013-04-15
  and so on

**I am having problems with overlapping dates if condition. I want to edit from_date of id 2 to a date in between 2013-02-22 and 2013-03-01 or to_date of period 1 to a date in between 2013-02-22 and 2013-03-01, but it only allows 1 as per my code below.**

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
function validate(id){

//id is passed as a parameter to the function
from_date = document.getElementById('from_date_' + id);
to_date= document.getElementById('to_date_' + id);

var from = new Date();
var to = new Date();

// I am able to split the string, .split("-") and convert it in date format

previous_to_date = document.getElementById("to_" + id);//id is one less
next_from_date = document.getElementById("from_date_" + id);//id is one more

current_from_date //I store it before editing the from date
current_to_date //Similarly for current from date

//from_date and to_date are the edited dates by the user
if (from_date > to_date){ alert("This date is invalid"); return false; }
//now to check for overlapping dates

**//This is the condition I am having problems with**
if ((from_date < current_from_date && from_date < previous_to_date) || (to_date > current_to_date && to_date > next_from_date) && from_date > current_to_date){
alert("These dates overlap,Please select another date");
return false;
}
//successful so now we submit the form...
}
```

Comment: Where is the question?

Comment: Can we see your existing code for that? Maybe we can build upon it. And `if` is not a loop, just for the sake of learning.

Comment: Yes my fault. I meant if condition

Answer (score 0):

> In simpler terms if there is a gap between the from date on current
>   period and the to date of the previous period, i should be able to
>   edit the change to minimize the gap to at most 1.

```
var to_previous = "2013-02-22"
var from = "2013-03-01"

var to_previous_millis = Date.parse(to_previous);
var from_millis = Date.parse(from);
one_day = 1000*60*60*24;

while( (from_millis - to_previous_millis) >= one_day) {
  current = new Date(from_millis);
  console.log(current.toUTCString());

  from_millis -= one_day
}

--output:--
Fri, 01 Mar 2013 00:00:00 GMT
Thu, 28 Feb 2013 00:00:00 GMT
Wed, 27 Feb 2013 00:00:00 GMT
Tue, 26 Feb 2013 00:00:00 GMT
Mon, 25 Feb 2013 00:00:00 GMT
Sun, 24 Feb 2013 00:00:00 GMT
Sat, 23 Feb 2013 00:00:00 GMT



var attempts = [
  "2013-2-28",
  "2013-2-23",
  "2013-2-22"
];

var len = attempts.length;

for (var i=0; i < len; ++i) {
  var attempt = attempts[i];
  attempt_millis = Date.parse(attempt);

  if (attempt_millis >= (to_previous_millis + one_day) ) {
    console.log(attempt + " : valid change");
  }
  else {
    console.log(attempt + " : invalid change");
  }

}

--output:--
2013-2-28 : valid change
2013-2-23 : valid change
2013-2-22 : invalid change
```

Comment: could you kindly suggest something with regards to my code please. Thanks

Comment: Yes, bin it. Then study my code.  In your code from_date is a string, and you are comparing it to other strings.  What do strings have to do with Dates?

Comment: I convert all the strings to dates.
I split the strings using .split("-") then string[0] is the year, string[1]-1 is the month and string[2] is the date. and then i convert it to a date using date.set([0],[1],[2]). I have checked this and it correctly translates the dates, so in my if i am comparing integers